# How to convert rows into column while inserting into temp table?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, rows, crosstab, dynamic-columns

I want to convert rows into column while inserting into temp table. I read somewhere about crosstab but not exactly sure how to use it for my purpose.

So suppose firstly I query like

```
select cat_id, category_name from category_tab;

cat_id        category_name

111              books    

112              pen

113              copy
```

Now I want a temp table which should be like

```
  s_no        books       pen      copy

   1                 

   2             

   3
```

s_no will be serial number and rows of previous query becomes the column in new temp table.

How can I achieve this task in postgres ?

Comment: yes, crosstab is exactly what you need. show the code sample and error please

Comment: I dont know how to use crosstab here. Can you please help me

Comment: There are many, many answers for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+crosstab